# Как отследить события мыши в python3

Tags: python, winapi, python-3.x, ctypes

Я нашел рабочий код слежения за координатами мыши в питоне, но при попытке найти что то подобное для того, чтобы отследить нажата мышь или нет (или какая, или колесико крутится) примера не нашел.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, во-первых, где смотреть (очень желательно на русском) описание вот функций которые есть в windll.user32? Именно оттуда я взял функцию для слежения за координатами.
И, собственно, как сделать так, чтобы код отслеживал нажатия (события в целом)?

Ещё хотелось бы знать суть того, как это работает, хотя бы общий принцип.

Привожу пример программы, которая на данный момент умеет грабить координаты (я ее упростил, но вроде рабочая должна быть):

```
from ctypes import *
import os
import time


class POINT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_int), ("y", c_int)]

def getCursorPosition(refreshTime):
    GetCursorPos = windll.user32.GetCursorPos
    p       = POINT()
    while True:     
        GetCursorPos(byref(p))
        print(p.x,p.y)
        time.sleep(refreshTime)

getCursorPosition(0.1)
```

Comment: по заголовку вопроса: если для окон своего приложения, то зависит от GUI framework таких как qt, gtk, tkinter. По телу вопроса: `GetAsyncKeyState()`. Похожий вопрос: [Getting mouse cursor position and button state on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10758202/4279)

Comment: в том то и дело, что нужно глобально получать. в независимости, от активности приложения. я могу в это время скажем в браузере работать.

Comment: Я понимаю,  GUI framework упомянул для людей, которые сюда пришли из веб-поисковика, прочитав только заголовок. Вторую часть (`GetAsyncKeyState()`) можно взять за основу для ответа на сам вопрос (в теле сообщения).

Comment: ага. теперь вас понимаю. ...я попробую вечером сделать прототип на питоне. отпишусь тогда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from ctypes import windll, Structure, c_ulong, byref, c_ushort
import time


class POINT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_ulong), ("y", c_ulong)]

VK_LBUTTON = 0x01               # Left mouse button
VK_RBUTTON = 0x02               # Right mouse button

def queryMousePosition():
    pt = POINT()
    windll.user32.GetCursorPos(byref(pt))
    return { "x": pt.x, "y": pt.y}
###########################################

for t in range(60):
    pos = queryMousePosition()
    print(pos)
    windll.user32.GetKeyState.restype = c_ushort
    if windll.user32.GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON):
        eee = 0
        print(eee)
    if windll.user32.GetKeyState(VK_RBUTTON):
        eee = 1
        print(eee)
    time.sleep(0.1)

Ниже результат
{'x': 911, 'y': 356}
{'x': 911, 'y': 356}
{'x': 935, 'y': 370}
{'x': 1003, 'y': 370}
{'x': 1046, 'y': 362}
{'x': 1069, 'y': 331}
{'x': 1073, 'y': 315}
{'x': 1073, 'y': 315}
{'x': 1066, 'y': 330}
Нажали ЛЕВУЮ кнопку
{'x': 1063, 'y': 336}
0
{'x': 1063, 'y': 336}
0
{'x': 1063, 'y': 360}
Нажали правую
{'x': 1081, 'y': 380}
0
1
{'x': 1081, 'y': 380}
0
1
{'x': 1081, 'y': 380}
0
1
Еще раз правую
{'x': 847, 'y': 351}
0
{'x': 847, 'y': 352}
0
{'x': 847, 'y': 359}
0
```

Comment: Тогда уж не `for t in range(60):`, а `while True:` :)

Comment: Проверил! Отлично работает! Спасибо!
К счастью ли, сожалению ли :) но эта задача уже для меня не актуальна(времени прошло много). 
Кстати, было бы здорово, если бы вы немного рассказали нам, как это работает? windll.user32 -- это уже не питон, это API windows?